# How to read multiple lines of input in lex and yacc?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I want the output as:

```
a=3   mov a,3
a=fs  mov b,fs
b=32  mov b,32
```

Program for 3 address intermediate code generation -
the lex file written for lexical analysis reads the input from command line and passes tokens:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <math.h>
%}
%%
[a-zA-Z]+ { yylval.var=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));
          strcpy(yylval.var,yytext);
         return ID;}
"="       return EQUALS;
[0-9]+    {yylval.num=atoi(yytext);return DIGIT;}


%%
```

The corresponding yacc file:

```
%{

#include "stdio.h"

#include "string.h"

int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}
%}


%union
{char *var;
 int num;
}


%token <var> ID 
%token <num> EQUALS DIGIT




%%
start : line 

line : ID EQUALS DIGIT {printf("MOV %s, %d\n",$1, $3);}
     | ID EQUALS ID    {printf("MOV %s, %s\n",$1, $3);}
     ;


%%

main()

{

yyparse();

return 0;

}

int yyerror(char *s)

{
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);

}
```

The output of running the above code (after linking between lex and yacc):

```
dsa=32                
MOV dsa, 32                // 3 address code generated

ds=342                     // but does not parse this line why??
syntax error
```

How do I get the output in the desired format?

Comment: There are several other problems here. You are malloc()-ing one byte yet you are copying an identifier of arbitrary length into it. You can just use `yylval.val = strdup(yytext);` here. You don't need to define token names and write special rules for all the special characters: it is a labour of Hercules. Instead put as the last line in yylex.l `. return yytext[0];` and just use the special characters directly in the grammar, e.g. as '='. This also has the advantage that illegal characters get into the parser error recovery system so you don't have to handle them at the lexical level at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your grammar only reads a single `line`

Maybe you wanted:

```
start : line
      | start line
      ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not clear exactly what you want.  Do you want a single call of `yyparse` to parse multiple lines (everything until you get an EOF)?  If so, rici's answer is what you want.  Or do you want `yyparse` to parse a single line and return, after which you can call it again to parse another line?  If that's what you want, you need to have your lexer recognize newlines and return an EOF for them:

```
[\n]    return -1;
```

However, with your current grammar, this will give you syntax errors for blank lines, which may or may not be what you want.