# How to enter multiple inputs in my Lex/Yacc program?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am writing a syntax/lexical analyser with lex/yacc to validate C-like variables declarations. But for some reason, after the compilation of all files, I can only enter one input at time for testing. I've seen some examples that work with multiple inputs, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my code:

Lex file

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%
int|float|char          return BUILTIN;
"["                     return OPEN_SQ; 
"]"                     return CLOSE_SQ;
","                     return COMMA;  
";"                     return SC;
[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]  return ID;
[0-9]                   return DIGIT;
\n                      return 0;
%%
```

Yacc file:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
//Deinição dos tokens
%token BUILTIN
%token ID
%token OPEN_SQ
%token CLOSE_SQ
%token SC
%token COMMA
%token DIGIT
%%
start:
    BUILTIN varlist SC {printf("VALID \n");}
    | BUILTIN ID OPEN_SQ DIGIT CLOSE_SQ SC {printf("VALID \n");} 
    | varlist: varlist COMMA ID | ID;
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    yyparse(); 
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s, INVALIDO\n",s);
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956358/how-to-reading-multiple-lines-of-input-in-lex-and-yacc

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068306/bison-only-reads-one-line/33069324#33069324